# Time series forecast with recurrent Elman network in neurolab

Tags: python, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, neurolab

I use the [Elman recurrent network from neurolab](https://pythonhosted.org/neurolab/ex_newelm.html) to predict a time series of continuous values. The network is trained from a sequence such that the input is the value at index `i` and the target is the value at index `i+1`.

To make predictions *beyond* the immediate next time step, the output of the net is feed back as input. If, for example, I intend to predict the value at `i+5`, I proceed as follows.

1. Input the value from `i`
2. Take the output and feed it to the net the as next input value (e.g. `i+1`)
3. Repeat 1. to 3. four more times
4. The output is a prediction of the value at`i+5`

So for predictions beyond the immediate next time step, *recurrent networks must be activated with the output from a previous activation.*

In most examples, however, the network is fed with an already complete sequence. See, for example, the functions [`train`](https://pythonhosted.org/neurolab/fw.html?highlight=step#neurolab.core.Net.train) and [`sim`](https://pythonhosted.org/neurolab/fw.html?highlight=step#neurolab.core.Net.sim) in the example behind the link above. The first function trains the network with an already complete list of examples and the second function activates the network with a complete list of input values.

After some digging in neurolab, I found the function [`step`](https://pythonhosted.org/neurolab/fw.html?highlight=step#neurolab.core.Net.step) to return a single output for a single input. Results from using `step` suggest, however, that the function does not retain the activation of the recurrent layer, which is crucial to recurrent networks.
[image: declining activation]

**How can I activate a recurrent Elman network in neurolab with a single input such that it maintains its internal state for the next single input activation?**

Comment: the same problem occurs with pybrain. im afraid either i did not understand the multi step prediction or it is just not very good...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it is quite normal for output which is generated from previous output sooner or later to converge towards a constant value. In effect, the output of a network cannot depend *only* on its previous output.

Answer (score 0):

I obtain the same result - constant . However I noticed something:

-> if you use 0 and 1 data, results improve. 0 - decrease 1 - increase. Result is no longer a constant.

-> try to use another variable to explain the targeted one as one of our colleagues already mentioned.