# Obtain output at each timestep in Keras LSTM

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

What I want to do is give the output of the LSTM at the current timestep as input to the LSTM in the next timestep. So I want the LSTM to predict the word at at the current time step and give this word as input to the next timestep. Is this can be done then:

How can the input and target data be specified during training i.e. in the `model.fit()` function?

Comment: just as additional information: i also tried to use the output of a recurrent network as next input. it turned out that errors accumulate and the output always converged towards some target value. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37971667/time-series-forecast-with-recurrent-elman-network-in-neurolab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do it directly in `keras` but you could do it using a `for` loop and `stateful` network. This works like this (assuming that you have your sentences stored as sequences of integers with `size=vocabulary_size`:

1. Define a stateful network which accepts one word and returns the following one:

   ```
   model = Input(batch_size=(batch_size, 1, 1)) 
   model = Embedding(size_of_vocabulary, output_size, input_length=1)(input)
   model = LSTM(lstm_1st_layer_size, return_sequences=True, stateful=True)(model)
   ....
   model = LSTM(lstm_nth_layer_size, return_sequences=True, stateful=True)(model)
   model = Dense(vocabulary_size, activation="softmax")

   model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="rmsprop")
   ```
2. Assuming that you have a numpy `array_of_samples` of examples `(preceding_word, next_word)` you could fit it by:

   ```
   model.fit(array_of_samples[:,0], array_of_samples[:,1])
   ```
3. Now you could try to predict stuff in a following manner:

   ```
   sentence = [starting_word]
   for i in range(len_of_sequence - 1):
       sentence.append(model.predict(numpy.array([[sentence[i]]).argmax())
   ```

Now `sentence` stores your newly created sentence